# Circle Tangent problem

Tags: geometry, circles

[image: A picture to give you something to go of]

Triangle $ABC$ is isosceles with $AB=AC$. A circle that is tangent to line $AB$ at $B$ intersects line $AC$ at points $P$ and $Q$. Prove that $BC$ bisects angle $ \widehat{PBQ}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $AB$ is a tangent to the circle we have $\angle ABP=\angle BQP$. So $\angle QBC=\angle ACB-\angle BQP=\angle ABC-\angle BQP=\angle ABC-\angle ABP=\angle PBC$. So $BC$ bisects $\angle ABC$.

[image]

Comment: I don't see why the initial equality… The line (BQ) has no reason to pass through the centre.

Comment: @Bernard Yeah, that is what I was thinking as well. If it did, could you please explain the reasoning to the first step anyway?

Comment: You mean $\angle ABP=\angle BQP$? That has nothing to do with $BQ$ passing through the centre (which it doesn't in general). It is a standard result that the angle subtended by a chord equals the angle between the chord and a tangent.

Comment: Why does  angle QBC =  angle ACB -  angle BQP @almagest

Comment: The angles in the triangle $BCQ$ sum to $180^o$, so do the angles $ACB$ and $PCQ$. But this is another standard result: the exterior angle of a triangle equals the sum of the other two.

Comment: $\angle QBC+\angle BQC+\angle BCQ=180^o$. Also $\angle BCQ+\angle ACB=180^o$. Hence $\angle ACB=180^o-\angle BCQ=(\angle QBC+\angle BQC+\angle BCQ)-\angle BCQ$, so $\angle ACB=\angle QBC+\angle BQC$ or $\angle QBC=\angle ACB-\angle BQC=\angle ACB-\angle BQP$.